# Como definir parametro dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class Checkbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title = 'Checkbox';
  // final String value ='CheckboxValue';




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BasePage(
        title: title,
        child: MetalonCheckbox(
          checkbox: ['lala', 'lele', 'lili'],
          enabled: true,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Levando em conta que está querendo passar o valor  do parâmetro via construtor ficaria:

```
void main() => runApp(Checkbox('meu parametro'));

class Checkbox extends StatelessWidget {
  Checkbox(this.title);
  final String title;
  // final String value ='CheckboxValue';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page ' + title),
    );
  }
}
```